# Shiny html output object that takes html code for easy copy and paste

Tags: html, r, shiny

I would like to create a Shiny R application that can take unformatted Stata code input by the user, add html tags, and return the entire block of code for easy copy and paste into an html publishing venue such as blogs or webpages.

I already have the R code that can handle the formatting [A Stata HTML syntax highlighter in R](http://www.econometricsbysimulation.com/2013/08/a-stata-html-formatter-in-r.html).  And most of the Shiny implementation seems very easy.  The major challenge I am having is creating an html textbox or other object that can easily take a reactive element from the Shiny's server.R and return it to the user without formatting the html tags.

Example:

Stata code input through a text box

```
clear
set obs 4000
gen id = _n
gen eta1 = rnormal()
gen eta2 = rnormal()
```

XX Shiny submit button XX

Return in another text box

```
<span style="color: #9900FF">set</span> <span style="color: #0000CC"><b>obs</b></span> 4000
<span style="color: #0000CC"><b>gen</b></span> id = <span style="color: #9900FF">_n</span>
<span style="color: #0000CC"><b>gen</b></span> eta1 = <span style="color: #9900FF">rnormal</span>()
<span style="color: #0000CC"><b>gen</b></span> eta2 = <span style="color: #9900FF">rnormal</span>()
```

Overall, I think this is generally a long question for a potentially very simple answer.  Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`renderText()` does not parse HTML tags. E.g. if you do:

```
output$code <- renderText({

  paste0(
    '<span style="color: #9900FF">set</span> <span style="color: #0000CC"><b>obs</b></span> 4000',
    '<span style="color: #0000CC"><b>gen</b></span> id = <span style="color: #9900FF">_n</span>',
    '<span style="color: #0000CC"><b>gen</b></span> eta1 = <span style="color: #9900FF">rnormal</span>',
    '<span style="color: #0000CC"><b>gen</b></span> eta2 = <span style="color: #9900FF">rnormal</span>'  
  )

})
```

Where this is your `ui.R`:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Code"),

  sidebarPanel(

  ),

  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("code")
  )

))
```

The content comes out as just text.

---

But since you haven't posted your ui.R (or index.html) I'm not sure how you are rendering your output. If you are having issues displaying raw text instead of parsed HTML you can always replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` like this:

```
html <- '<span>text</span>'
x <- gsub('<', '&lt;', html)
gsub('>', '&gt;', x)
```

Which will produce: `&lt;span&gt;text&lt;/span&gt;` and should not be displayed as parsed HTML in your browser.